# Upload QuoVadis EV Certificate to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I am trying to upload my QuoVadis EV Certificate to AWS. I have tried using the Console as well as the CLI according to [these](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ssl-server-cert.html#example-rsa-private-key) instructions. With no luck.

I have tried the [certificate chain](https://support.quovadisglobal.com/kb/a298/how-do-i-install-an-ssl-certificate-into-nginx.aspx) in all orderings of  QuoVadis Global SSL ICA G2 certificate and Root GA 2. With the root last, or not included at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the instructions on the website as well as those that I received with my certificate zip archive are wrong.

When checking the certificate (for example [here](https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html)) it turns out it was not signed with QuoVadis Global SSL ICA G2 but with [QuoVadis Global SSL ICA G1](https://www.quovadisglobal.com/QVRepository/DownloadRootsAndCRL/QuoVadisEVSSLICAG1-PEM.aspx).

As soon as I replaced the intermediary certificate, the upload worked fine.